# How to do simple XML schema validation with no namespaces in C#

Tags: c#, xml-validation

I have generated a set of classes using xsd.exe and created an XML document from the resulting generated code.  I would now like to validate the serialized class instance against the original xsd.

My XML is like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<MyRoot xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   -- rest of XML document here
</MyRoot>
```

My XSD is like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
   <xs:element name="MyRoot" type="MyRootType"/>
   -- MyRootType definition and rest of XSD
</xs:schema>
```

When I try to validate the XML using a XmlReader, I get the following error:
"The 'MyRoot' element is not declared."

What could be wrong?

Comment: Does the error indicate that the MyRoot element was found to be missing from the XML (which it isn't) or that the MyRoot element was found to be missing from the XSD (which it also isn't).

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The approach was correct, but the XSD was not infact being read.  I corrected this and it worked as expected.

Comment: Could you describe your solution?

Answer (score 1):

In your MyRoot element, you need to add the location of the XSD.  I would also recommend defining the namespace (unless you have good reason not to).

```
<api:MyRoot  xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance'
   xmlns:api='http://www.myserver.com/schema'
   xsi:schemaLocation='http://www.myserver.com/schema http://www.myserver.com/schema/websuiterecord.xsd'>
</api:MyRoot>
```

This way, the validation tool knows where to find your XSD to validate your XML against.

Comment: Ideally I would like to not touch either the XML or the XSD but just tell the reader how to read it.  Is this possible?

Comment: The XML has to be in the current format as it is sent to another 3rd party system.  The XSD could be tweaked slightly if needed.

Comment: You should be able to give the location of an XSD to the xml reader through a method or constructor or something.